# Silverlight: Lazy loading from nHibernate

Tags: c#, silverlight, nhibernate

I've recently been using/working on an open source project for Flex/Java/BlazeDS which facilitates lazy loading of Hibernate entities & collections in Flex.  (Ie., solves the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` exception when serializing)

This issue has long been a problem for Flex/Java/Hibernate developers.

[dpHibernate](http://code.google.com/p/dphibernate/) solves this problem, providing efficient serialization & lazy loading of collections.

I'm wondering if the same issue exists for Silverlight, if it's already been solved, and whether looking at a port of dpHibernate is needed/worthwhile?

Answer (score 0):

I stand to be corrected, but I don't think there is support for nHibernate in Silverlight.